# Why aren't web.config AppSettings values overwritten with Azure WebApp blade 'App Settings' values?

Tags: azure, web-config, azure-web-app-service

My .NET WebApp overrides some web.config appSetting key/values in the blade's 'App Settings'. However, when I try to access these using  WebConfigurationManager or ConfigurationManager, the values from the VS transformed web.config are returned.

If I query using Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPSETTING_"...), the expected values from the blade are returned.

Per this documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure) I was expecting these injected values to be accessible via AppSettings[..].

Does anyone know why the values aren't being set?

---

Additional info: Presently I am publishing the ASP.NET MVC project from Visual Studio to an Azure WebApp. The VS project has a 'UAT' Configuration and corresponding web.UAT.config tranform, which works correctly when inspecting obj\UAT\TransformWebConfig\transformed. The publish profile is using the UAT configuration and targeting a corresponding UAT slot in the WebApp and the app deploys correctly.

Comment: Try to check the values in SCM environment settings and let us know if it is reflected the same.

Comment: It appears that the problem may be caused by defining appSettings within a <location> element (whether in the primary web.config or the Configuration-transformed version.

Even if no keys are added, just defining the location/appSettings element will prevent the root appSettings being used.

I would have expected the root values to be available unless overridden in the location node. Suspect may be a limitation of the way values are injected at runtime.

I'll probably have to work around this in code, as there doesn't seem to be a way to manage location/appSetting values in the portal.

Comment: To investigate this issue, we need to capture dumps and validate the same. So, I would suggest you create a support ticket which will help us to check the behavior and can find the root cause of this issue: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/options/?v=17.33https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-reques

Comment: Thanks. I have opened a support request within the portal.